# Get first image with new DOMDocument()

Tags: php, dom

I am trying to get the first image of some HTML. I know how to achieve all images, using a for loop. However, I am struggling to get **just** the first.

I have the following code:

```
function get_first_image_b() {

    global $post, $posts;
    ob_start();
    ob_end_clean();
    $html= $post->post_content;

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($html);
    $img = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
    print_r($img);

}
```

Which spits out:

```
(
    [length] => 4
)
```

Would anyone know how I could turn the first of this into a string/or something usable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the `item` method:

```
echo $img->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
```

Comment: @tmyie that is because of `echo`.  Just use `var_dump($img->item(0))` if you want to see the actual object information.

Comment: That getAttribute works! How did you get that, from: `DOMElement Object ( [tagName] => img [schemaTypeInfo] => [nodeName] => img [nodeValue] => [nodeType] => 1 [parentNode] => (object value omitted) [childNodes] => (object value omitted) [firstChild] => [lastChild] => [previousSibling] => [attributes] => (object value omitted) [ownerDocument] => (object value omitted) [namespaceURI] => [prefix] => [localName] => img [baseURI] => [textContent] => )` ?

Comment: DOMElement::getAttribute. It extends DOMNode.

Answer (score 0):

The `DOMNodeList` object implements traversable, so you can just do this.

```
$img = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
$first_image = $img->current(); // get first element in list
```

Comment: `$img = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
$first_image = $img->current(); // get first element in list
echo $first_image;` also produces an error. "Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string"

Comment: @tmyie Don't `echo` it.  It is an object. Your error comes about because that object must not have `__toString()` implemented.